# Gnome 3 Nautilus - Custom bookmarks

Tags: 13.10, gnome, nautilus, gnome-classic, bookmarks

I'm just upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 with Gnome 3 Classic.

Could you say me how I can create bookmark [link or signet] on the left navigation panel of Nautilus ?

Before upgrading I had a bookmarks option in main menu...

But I didn't find it in this new version ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's under the "gear" at the right:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04 (Files 3.14.3), you just drag the item from the right side to the left sidebar. You'll see a new row appear called "New Bookmark". Drop the item on the "New Bookmark" area.